# Some Tools in Editor Toolbar Grayed out

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, editing, tools

I am using ArcMap 10.8 with a Basic Level License and Windows 10.

I am in Data View.  Have layer in TOC selected and started Edit session.
I have removed the definition query from the feature class and could create new feature if I wanted to on this feature class.

However, some of my Editor toolbars are enabled, but some of them are grayed out.  I can edit vertices, trace. and reshape features, but not cut polygons.  I did last week!

I am not new to ArcMap which is acting  unexpectedly of late.
I have already closed out and renamed my normal.mxt template.

Thoughts?

Looks like this
[image]

Comment: Have you run Check/Repair Geometry on that feature class, closed ArcMap and re-opened it to try again?

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the layer has been set to "Not Selectable"